# Android Programmatically open SELECT INPUT METHOD tab on Button Click

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

I have show the available virtual keyboard by specifying

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS), 0);
```

Now I want select input method by programmatically
which action I can choose??[like this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvQ9I.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piece of code is fulfill my requirements:

```java
InputMethodManager imeManager = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imeManager.showInputMethodPicker();
```